# Geoserver ImageMosaic ignores existing datastore.properties (connect to PostGIS) and automatically generates index using shapefile

Tags: postgis, geoserver, spatial-index, image-mosaic, time-series

I am new to Geoserver. I am trying to publish a WMS service for a raster time series using the ImageMosaic plugin in Geoserver. I am using the sample dataset and instructions at this [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html#configuration-files)

I want to use postgres/postgis to map the time values to corresponding layers and created **datastore.properties**

```
SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
host=localhost
port=5432
database=postgis_sample
schema=public
user=postgres
passwd=qwer1234
Loose\ bbox=true
Estimated\ extends=false
validate\ connections=true
Connection\ timeout=10
preparedStatements=true
```

But when I attempt to create a new store -> Raster data - ImageMosaic -> choose data directory and save, Geoserver ignores my datastore.properties file and uses the default settings by creating shapefile and automatically rewrites and generates a new datastore.properties file. This should not happen according to the documentation. The postgres/postgis service is running and I am able to connect and write from the windows commandline. I also grant all permissions to the public schema. Could someone point out what is going wrong here?

I am using Geoserver 2.11.4, PostgreSQL 10 with PostGIS 2.4.4.

**indexer.properties**

```
Caching=false
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
```

**timeregex.properties**

```
regex=[0-9]{8}
```

EDIT:
I have attached the log entries after following the above procedures in this [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/raw/pUyQFwvb).

Comment: please look in the log file and find the relevant entries, then add them to the question.

Comment: @IanTurton I have included a link to the geoserver log files. There seems to be nothing about attempts connect to postgis in the log.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the part that is creating the mosaic, also you might need to turn the log level up to geoserver_developer

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for pointing that out. I have added the updated developer_log at the link. Kindly have a look!

Comment: kay, you need to create the mosaic again (or a new one) so I can see what goes wrong, while that is happening, in the logfile.

Comment: @IanTurton Hi Ian. I changed to developer_log and then created the image mosaic again. The log I have attached captures all these tasks. Is it not as expected?